# Unordered list indent css, php, xhtml

Tags: php, css, xhtml

I'm new to all this. I've got a template for a mock website I'm working on. The left menu was fine in the template. Since I've changed the left menu to appear in PHP it keeps indenting to the left. I've tried changing the css to have margin-left = 0px and other things But it remains the same. You can see that padding has 30px left but I changed that to 0px and still remained indented and the ticks were over the text.

[indent http://i.minus.com/iwFNaTVEdSzZw.png](http://i.minus.com/iwFNaTVEdSzZw.png)

CSS

```
ul.left_menu{
width:196px;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
}
ul.left_menu li{
margin:0px;
list-style:none;
}
ul.left_menu li.odd a{
width:166px;
height:25px;
display:block;
background:url(images/checked.png) no-repeat left #dad0d0;
background-position:5px 5px;
border-bottom:1px #FFFFFF solid;
text-decoration:none;
color:#504b4b;
padding:0 0 0 30px;
line-height:25px
 } ;
```

xHTML

```
<div class="left_content">
  <div class="title_box">Categories</div>
  <ul class="left_menu">
    <li class="odd">
  <?php  include("category_menu.php"); ?>
    </li>
```

Edit

```
//take the book types to be used on the left menu (leftColumn.php)
$query_category_menu = "SELECT category_id, category_name FROM      computineerCategory";

$query_category_menu_result = mysql_query($query_category_menu)
 or die(mysql_error());

echo '<ul>';
while($type_category_data = mysql_fetch_array($query_category_menu_result))
{
    print "<a href = 'category.php?categoryid=".$type_category_data["category_id"]."'>".$type_category_data["category_name"]."</a>";
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: can you post whats inside `category_menu.php`? I'd imagine you've output an extra `<ul>` in there, but can't say for certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the

```
echo '<ul>'

echo '</ul>'
```

from the category_menu file you don't need to add these twice